# Different spinner layout for collapsed spinner

Tags: android, spinner, row

I have a `Spinner` for which I modified the item layout to show two rows. When the `Spinner` is in it's "open" state it looks great, but when it is collapsed I want it to show only the first row from the layout as it currently showing the two rows. How can I make this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set the spinner adapter, you provide a layout that is for the closed spinner.  You can specify a different layout for the dropdown using `setDropDownViewResource`

Quick example:

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity(), R.array.States,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.listlayout_black);
    final Spinner states = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.mbr_state_spinner);
    states.setAdapter(adapter);
```